# Excel cell into list in Python

Tags: python, excel, list, for-loop

So I have an Excel column which contains Python lists.

[image]

The problem is that when I'm trying to loop through it in Python it reads the cells as str. Attempt to split it makes the items in a list generate as e.g.:

list = ["['Gdynia',", "'(2262011)']"]

list[0] = "['Gdynia,'"

list[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olzRj.png) = "'(2261011)']"

I want only to get the city name which is e.g. 'Gdynia' or 'Tczew'. Any idea how can I make it possible?

Comment: Did you try to use pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string at a desired symbol, `'` would be good for your example.
Then you get a list of strings and you can chose the part you need.

```
str = "['Gdynia',", "'(2262011)']"
str_parts = str.split("'") #['[', 'Gdynia', ',', '(2262011)', ']']
city = str_parts[1] #'Gdynia'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with re:

```
import re

data = ["['Gdynia', '(2262011)'",
        "['Tczew', '(2214011)']",
        "['Zory', ’(2479011)']"]

r = re.compile("'(.*?)'")
print(*[r.search(s).group(1) for s in data], sep='\n')
```

**Output**

```
Gdynia
Tczew
Zory
```